# Self-Hosting WCF and System.ServiceModel.FaultException

Tags: c#, wcf, self-hosting, faultexception

I have a simple WCF Service Library Project (call this Project W) with a handful of DLLs in directory X. I set the startup directory of W to X, all methods work correctly using WcfServiceHost in Visual Studio 2010.

I want to self-host W, so, I created a console Project (call this Project C), added a reference to W, set the startup directory of W to X, then have essentially the following main lines of code

```
var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(EvalService));
host.Open();
```

When I now test the methods in W, I am getting `System.ServiceModel.FaultException` with `{"The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"}`.

What can this mean? How can I tell what module it is trying to load?

I am fairly new to both C# and WCF, any hint would be apprecited.

Comment: use [fuslogvw.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.100).aspx) in the .Net SDK

Comment: Thanks, @rene, nothing shows up in fuslogvw.exe, any further ideas?

Comment: Might be a non .Net dll that is missing, try [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and look for FAILED in the Result column.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to event AppDomain.AssemblyResolve and see in the debugger, which assembly is problematic.

```
AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
currentDomain.AssemblyResolve += OnAssemblyResolve;

...

private static Assembly OnAssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
   Console.WriteLine(args.RequestingAssembly); //set breakpoint there
   return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine if this error is in the service or the client.

From the error message it seems this is a service side error. You could implement IErrorHandler from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg281715.aspx.

This will give you access to all errors in your service. You can then log all exceptions and their inner exceptions.

Hope this helps.